# Is there a way to ask a question on a well received answer without commenting on it?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, accepted-answer

I really get lot of question while reading the accepted answer on SO(basically doubts or further clarification in easy language), but i don't feel like commenting on it as it might disturb the answer or it might not be a reasonable question to ask for that answer. So, Is there any particular way by which i can ask for further clarification/doubts on an answer by not commenting on that answer?

Also,is it possible to ask a separate question based on a well voted answer?(basically by pointing to particular answer by providing its link or something like this.)

Comment: I don't get it. A comment is going to "disturb" the answer? If you find it's unreasonable, then delete it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, ask it as a new question, and provide a reference to the answer that prompted your new question. Try to make the question stand on it's own so that it doesn't rely too much on the other answer, and double check that it isn't a duplicate.

Be sure to provide any attempts you made at solving it as well, if applicable.

Comment: Thanks. But there are situation where a code or particular text is very complex for me and every person except me on that conversation is easily able to get that, what should i do for this?Is there a way by which i can ask for further clarification without harming the answer

Comment: depends.. might just be a case where you'll need to break it down and try to figure out which parts of it you don't understand. Just dropping a piece of code and asking what it does or how it works may not get received well unless you're specific in what parts of it you don't understand and why.

Comment: Yeah. But sometimes its hard actually pointing out the problem. like I am a newbie and the level of answer is pretty high so I want the answer to be explained in simpler terms even though the actual answer is clearly understandable for others. And also sometimes the problem is not quite reasonable to be asked as a separate question, so what should i do in such a case.

Comment: Not much you can do, unfortunately. If it isn't good enough to be it's own valid question, and you don't want to leave a comment, you're out of options. You could take it to an applicable chat room, but... they might not appreciate it there either.

Comment: Yeah, I think so but I think a new feature should be added to SO that deals with this stuff(it may provide reputation to the one that provides answer in total layman terms or something like this). Also this feature will help the newbies to learn at much faster rate.

Comment: @PrayagSharma Please note that asking a new question that is "Can someone explain this answer?" won't fly at all.  If you need simple clarification on a point of the answer, use comments for this.

Comment: But I think simply pointing a thing(for clarification) which everyone gets (except me) would make the conversation dirt(and even make me look like a fool :)  and also I can't do this for every doubt that I get after reading an answer )

Comment: As a newbie one gets a lot of doubts and needs answer to those questions in layman terms , I think one must have patience and just keep learning till he/she gets to a level where one gets that particular concept/topic . Also a feature should be added(if possible) to SO that do something about this problem.

Comment: @PrayagSharma What kind of feature, to do something about which problem? A question-on-an-answer-that-is-not-a-comment feature? PS. World English prefers "question" to "doubt". See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question.

Comment: @torazaburo I don't think you have read the question and comments carefully.Please read the comments and the question and you'll get what I am trying to say(also by doubt i mean further clarification) .

Comment: If you want to request a new feature, create a feature request. Please note however that it is VERY hard to create a feature request here that is well received. you must first do the research and provide reasoning for why this feature is needed and what problem it will be solving.

Comment: @PrayagSharma I read your question very carefully. The more I read it the more confused I got. If you think your comment is going to "disturb" the question in some mysterious way, or that it might not be "reasonable", then don't make the comment, problem solved. In terms of the your second question, whether "it is possible to ask a separate question", why on earth would it not be possible? Is someone stopping you from posting a new question? If you are so unsure about what you are asking, why would you choose to ask a new Q which will be downvoted and closevoted, intead of leaving a comment?

Comment: Sometimes its hard pointing out the doubt with a well voted answer.Example:I am a newbie and while reading certain answer I don't get some piece of the answer as the level of answer is pretty high(for me) so I want the answer to be explained in simpler terms even though the actual answer is clearly understandable for others(except me).In such a situation I don't think to add a comment to the answer as it might deviate the answer from its topic (as it might require some other explanation to my comment) and if I don't comment I will be stuck with a question/doubt(from the answer that I read).

Comment: Also I can't do this(comment) for every doubt that I get after reading an answer. And I have completely understood that I can ask a question based on answer, Thanks @KevinB for the answer.

Comment: What i think is If comment is not deviating the answer only then it must be made, other wise one must ask a new question pointing the particular answer in his/her question. I think this is what I have got from everyone in this conversation. @KevinB is absolutely correct and also +1 for his patience(for bearing me :) ) .